# How to fix issue with sql query execution using call back

Tags: node.js, azure-sql-database

I am having problem with sql query execution using callback, I never worked on the node.js, so looking for some guidance and get going.

Tried with having database connection in same file, but unable to execute when having the database connection in another file.

**DatabaseManager.js**

```js
var Tedious = require('tedious'); 
var Connection = Tedious.Connection;
var Request = Tedious.Request;


function connect(cb) { 
  var config = {
    userName: 'dddff',
    password: 'fsfdsf',
    server: '12345.database.windows.net',
    options:
      {
        database: '12345',
        encrypt: true
      }
  }; 

  var connection = new Connection(config);


  connection.on('connect', function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return; 
    }

    console.log('CONNECTED TO DATABASE');
    cb(connection);
   
    
    
    });
  }

module.exports = connect;
```

**app.js**

```js
var connect = require('./DatabaseManager');

bot.dialog('profileDialog', (session) => {
  session.send('Hello Message', session.message.text);

  console.log('Creating a connection');

  connect(function(connection) {

    console.log('Reading rows from the Table.');

    // Execute queries here and how to frame the syntax here?
    
    connection.query("select FNAME from StudentProfile where ID=1"),
      function(err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
      }
  });
})
```

I expect the output of select statement result on the console.

Comment: This has been addressed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54383652/in-node-how-to-execute-sql-from-global-database-connection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Node, how to execute sql from global database connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54383652/in-node-how-to-execute-sql-from-global-database-connection)

Comment: @Alberto Morillo, Yes as I mentioned in my previous comment. This can be closed.

Comment: I cannot close it on my own. 4 more votes are needed. Thank you.